# PyQt button signal with .ui file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to print a simple text to show that the Ok or Cancel button in my dialog was pressed. QuantityDialog loads the "quantitydialog.ui" file and builds the dialog window. I believe `clicked()` is the signal for button press, so I overload it with my function that prints a simple text.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QuantityDialog()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

class QuantityDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("quantitydialog.ui",self)

        self.buttonBox.clicked = self.buttonPress

    def buttonPress(self):
        print ("button pressed")
```

quantitydialog.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>180</width>
    <height>81</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Quantity Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>181</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string>tsp</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="qtyText">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Quantity:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
      <property name="standardButtons">
       <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
      </property>
      <property name="centerButtons">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Right now it is not printing the "button pressed" text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `self.buttonBox.clicked = self.buttonPress` to `self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.buttonPress)`

Comment: more information: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signalsl

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late but..
You actually need to use the .connect function to respond to press events.

`self.buttonBox.clicked = self.buttonPress`